# Model for exponential decay with lots of zeros

Tags: r, model, nonlinear-regression, treatment-effect

I am trying to test for the effect of a treatment on a response variable. The response variable decays over time in what I believe is an exponential way. The measurement doesn't go below zero, so there are loads of zeros in the data.

The measurements looks like this

```
p <- ggplot(dat, aes(time, value, color = treatment)) + geom_point()
```

[image]

I've attempted fitting `lm()`:

```
dat.lm <- lm(log(value + 1) ~ time + treatment, data = dat)
```

and the diagnostics are very ordinary, and predictions are poor.

```
newdat <- expand.grid(treatment = factor(1:2), time = 0:6)
newdat$pred <- predict(dat.lm, newdat)
p2 <- p + geom_line(data = newdat, aes(x = time, y = exp(pred) - 1))
```

[image]

I would like to be able to both test for the significance of the effect of the treatment, as well as estimate parameters for the decay function. I have also had a go with `nls()`, and a cubic model at least fits better at time == 0, but still not great, and doesn't really make sense.

```
dat.cubic <- predict(lm(value~time+I(time^2)+I(time^3) + treatment, data = dat), newdat)
newdat$cubic <- dat.cubic
p2 + geom_line(data = newdat, aes(x = time, y = cubic), linetype = "dashed")
```

[image]

To repeat, my main question is how to test the effect of treatment with this data, and secondly, what is the best way to fit the model?

My data:

```
structure(list(time = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 
3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 
4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 
5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 
6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 6, 
6), value = c(382.49, 377.13, 422.72, 377.52, 410.48, 435.78, 
399.74, 540.5, 481.29, 455.53, 439.56, 368.63, 421.92, 490.87, 
384.1, 478.92, 327.94, 403.7, 410.99, 332.97, 396.78, 420.85, 
359.82, 474.43, 371.25, 130.92, 84.87, 199.36, 150.84, 112.1, 
111.78, 183.84, 144.01, 163.16, 92.86, 237.2, 172.71, 161.1, 
92.02, 204.17, 183.41, 140, 100.93, 62.52, 152.94, 116.63, 220.2, 
145.3, 168.9, 155.89, 68.3, 44.44, 57.63, 0, 69.72, 48.96, 64.12, 
44.45, 22.9, 40.06, 25.48, 12.94, 30.43, 53.14, 53.16, 31.64, 
18.39, 55.73, 35.15, 44.96, 55.55, 0, 1.36, 30.73, 55.1, 15.71, 
22.66, 0, 26.53, 8.44, 51.93, 0, 0, 0, 0, 10.42, 16.42, 0, 28.17, 
0, 13.21, 48.45, 10.64, 40.52, 10.34, 15.97, 0, 29.81, 21.88, 
36.6, 0, 0, 7.13, 2.84, 12.94, 6.09, 0, 0, 0.54, 11.6, 15.58, 
5.39, 0, 7.67, 0, 0, 5.3, 0, 19.28, 4.12, 0, 9.96, 0, 10.8, 3.48, 
1.98, 1.74, 2.49, 1.79, 0.43, 3.62, 2.37, 0.87, 2.02, 0.27, 1.63, 
1.25, 3.43, 2.73, 1.76, 2.22, 1.6, 1.27, 2.31, 2.3, 0.64, 1.8, 
2.17, 2.52, 0.5, 0.44, 1.02, 1.19, 0.93, 0, 1.48, 0, 1.31, 0, 
0.78, 0.13, 0.9, 0, 1.79, 0.8, 0.21, 0.74, 1.81, 0, 0.98, 0, 
1.59, 0.58, 0.89, 1.48, 379.16, 393.21, 412.4, 426.87, 375.65, 
438.64, 399.23, 454.42, 450.48, 473.15, 473.4, 396.43, 430.82, 
464.84, 370.04, 462.76, 422.85, 435.26, 428.96, 396.91, 460.68, 
485.32, 404.56, 464.46, 475.78, 198.16, 130.74, 38.98, 114.62, 
54.07, 89.64, 74.2, 60.19, 64.38, 70.59, 35.57, 17.4, 105.75, 
67.31, 102.33, 123.3, 131.07, 94.44, 70.1, 62.25, 122.39, 22.49, 
120.74, 63.28, 61.21, 0, 23.05, 32.91, 0, 49.65, 44.3, 3.58, 
20.8, 31.15, 0, 29.53, 36.56, 55.63, 0, 57.8, 4.9, 0, 28.29, 
17.23, 64.23, 4.94, 0, 31.43, 56.98, 6.46, 0, 0, 1.44, 0, 0, 
0.23, 0, 5.83, 0, 0, 7.02, 3.23, 3.52, 2.65, 11.88, 0, 2.63, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 11.29, 5.1, 4.66, 13.05, 3.18, 1.52, 0, 0, 5.07, 
2.15, 0, 2.7, 0, 6.75, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2.49, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.02, 3.27, 
11.94, 3.89, 3.22, 0, 0.76, 0, 0.68, 1.05, 0, 1.04, 0, 0, 2.04, 
0.86, 0.03, 0, 0.56, 0, 0.03, 0.5, 0, 0, 0.95, 0, 0, 1.2, 0, 
0.23, 0, 0, 0, 0.65, 0.67, 0, 0.87, 0.95, 0, 0.89, 0.91, 0, 0, 
1.74, 1.09, 0, 1.04, 0.21, 0.36, 0, 0, 1.8, 0.04, 0, 0, 0.71), 
    treatment = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("1", 
    "2"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("time", "value", "treatment"
), row.names = c(NA, 350L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: "measurement doesn't go below zero" because values below zero are not possible, were nor observed, or your measurement instrument does not allow negative values?

Comment: Are not possible. Zero is zero. It's a measurement of how far a material extends before fracturing, so negative values are not possible

Answer (score 4):

Provided there is some justification for an exponential decay model, you could try the `gnls` function from package `nlme`. This allows you to compare treatments and model variance heterogeneity. Here is something to get you started:

```
library(ggplot2)
p <- ggplot(DF, aes(time, value, color = treatment)) + geom_point()
```

Get starting values by fitting separate `nls` models:

```
coef(nls(value ~ C * exp(-k*time), data = DF[DF$treatment == 1,], start = list(C=400, k=1)))
#         C          k 
#415.729905   1.080539 

coef(nls(value ~ C * exp(-k*time), data = DF[DF$treatment == 2,], start = list(C=400, k=1)))
#         C          k 
#430.787442   1.606167
```

Now use `gnls`:

```
library(nlme)
fit <- gnls(value ~ C * exp(-k*time), 
            data = DF, 
            params = list(C ~ treatment, k ~ treatment), 
            start = list(C = c(415, 15), k = c(1.1, 0.5)),
            weights = varExp(-0.8, form = ~ time),
            control = gnlsControl(nlsTol = 0.1))
```

I use an exponential variance structure (without dependence on treatment) here, but you could try some alternatives. Note that I had to strongly increase `nlsTol` to achieve a successful fit. Use the result with caution (but it looks pretty good):

```
summary(fit)
#Generalized nonlinear least squares fit
#  Model: value ~ C * exp(-k * time) 
#  Data: DF 
#       AIC      BIC    logLik
#  2485.028 2508.176 -1236.514
#
#Variance function:
# Structure: Exponential of variance covariate
# Formula: ~time 
# Parameter estimates:
#     expon 
#-0.8035687 
#
#Coefficients:
#                 Value Std.Error  t-value p-value
#C.(Intercept) 413.5077 15.976589 25.88210  0.0000
#C.treatment2    9.7849 24.062902  0.40664  0.6845
#k.(Intercept)   1.0932  0.021132 51.73149  0.0000
#k.treatment2    0.4104  0.061657  6.65565  0.0000
#
# Correlation: 
#              C.(In) C.trt2 k.(In)
#C.treatment2  -0.664              
#k.(Intercept)  0.629 -0.418       
#k.treatment2  -0.216  0.456 -0.343
#
#Standardized residuals:
#        Min          Q1         Med          Q3         Max 
#-2.49675931 -0.55858325 -0.02101141  0.53929573  4.36616094 
#
#Residual standard error: 92.79678 
#Degrees of freedom: 350 total; 346 residual

plot(fit)
```

[image: residual plot]

Now plot the result:

```
newdata <- expand.grid(time = seq(0, 6, length.out = 100), treatment = factor(1:2))
newdata$value <- predict(fit, newdata = newdata)

p + geom_line(data = newdata)
```

[image: resulting plot]

In a next step one could try removing the dependence of C on treatment from the model. That might help to achieve better convergence ...

Answer (score 2):

The main idea seems to be that an idea of exponential decay is not contradicted by observed zeros. You don't spell it out, but the implication seems to be that reported zero may be a question of what can be recorded, rather than an indication that the physical effect is exactly zero.

As the mean response given predictors should be positive, that's consistent with a generalized linear model with logarithmic link. Although the response is continuous, a Poisson family is not as crazy as it may seem, although a first impression is that a gamma family may be preferable. These results are from Stata. Either model gives a signal that treatment is of importance.

```
. glm value time i.treatment, link(log) f(poisson) vce(robust)
note: value has noninteger values

Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood = -7081.5897  
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood = -2505.8521  
Iteration 2:   log pseudolikelihood = -2465.8071  
Iteration 3:   log pseudolikelihood = -2465.6709  
Iteration 4:   log pseudolikelihood = -2465.6709  

Generalized linear models                          No. of obs      =       350
Optimization     : ML                              Residual df     =       347
                                                   Scale parameter =         1
Deviance         =  3637.519172                    (1/df) Deviance =  10.48276
Pearson          =  3476.433202                    (1/df) Pearson  =  10.01854

Variance function: V(u) = u                        [Poisson]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                    [Log]

                                                   AIC             =  14.10669
Log pseudolikelihood = -2465.670862                BIC             =  1604.816

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       value |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        time |  -1.263214   .0282436   -44.73   0.000    -1.318571   -1.207858
 2.treatment |  -.1371954   .0381799    -3.59   0.000    -.2120265   -.0623642
       _cons |   6.104811   .0262819   232.28   0.000       6.0533    6.156323
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. predict poisson
(option mu assumed; predicted mean value)

. glm value time i.treatment, link(log) f(gamma) vce(robust)

Iteration 0:   log pseudolikelihood = -1496.1011  
Iteration 1:   log pseudolikelihood = -1220.2277  
Iteration 2:   log pseudolikelihood = -1206.8443  
Iteration 3:   log pseudolikelihood = -1206.2852  
Iteration 4:   log pseudolikelihood = -1206.2844  
Iteration 5:   log pseudolikelihood = -1206.2844  

Generalized linear models                          No. of obs      =       350
Optimization     : ML                              Residual df     =       347
                                                   Scale parameter =  .8891775
Deviance         =  154.6345707                    (1/df) Deviance =  .4456328
Pearson          =  308.5445848                    (1/df) Pearson  =  .8891775

Variance function: V(u) = u^2                      [Gamma]
Link function    : g(u) = ln(u)                    [Log]

                                                   AIC             =  6.910197
Log pseudolikelihood = -1206.284432                BIC             = -1878.068

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
             |               Robust
       value |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
        time |  -1.123467   .0244255   -46.00   0.000     -1.17134   -1.075594
 2.treatment |  -.6744363   .1057609    -6.38   0.000    -.8817238   -.4671487
       _cons |   6.154146    .085826    71.70   0.000      5.98593    6.322362
------------------------------------------------------------------------------

. groups treatment time gamma poisson, sepby(treatment) show(f)

  +-----------------------------------------------+
  | treatm~t   time      gamma    poisson   Freq. |
  |-----------------------------------------------|
  |        1      0   470.6648   448.0081      25 |
  |        1      1   153.0369   126.6715      25 |
  |        1      2   49.76003   35.81559      25 |
  |        1      3    16.1795   10.12664      25 |
  |        1      4   5.260774   2.863244      25 |
  |        1      5   1.710543   .8095644      25 |
  |        1      6   .5561841   .2288993      25 |
  |-----------------------------------------------|
  |        2      0   239.7771   390.5735      25 |
  |        2      1   77.96366   110.4322      25 |
  |        2      2   25.34993   31.22403      25 |
  |        2      3   8.242542     8.8284      25 |
  |        2      4   2.680067   2.496176      25 |
  |        2      5   .8714252   .7057781      25 |
  |        2      6   .2833444   .1995544      25 |
  +-----------------------------------------------+
```

I add a graph of predicted values for each time and treatment on logarithmic scale.

[image]